# React Native - Store data in local DB/AsyncStorage with no Internet connection?

Tags: react-native, offline, mobile-application, asyncstorage

What's the best way to make an offline friendly app where my requirement is to never stop the user from submitting data regardless of internet connectivity.

When connectivity is there POST data directly to the online server and when there's no connection then store data in some kind of local storage(reliable) until the connection is established again in which case send data immediately to the online server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library, i've used in multiple projects of mine

[react-native-netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) will return you a callback when app is not connected with internet

you can perform and handle further action there
*

```
A small example
now you'll get the value in redux if your device is connected or not
```

*

**and remember it doesn't work well in simulator test on real device**

```js
import React from 'react';
// import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet ,NetInfo} from 'react-native';
import {toggleNetworkState} from '../../actions/list';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

function MiniOfflineSign() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.offlineText}>No Internet Connection</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

class OfflineNotice extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isConnected: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    this.setState({
        isConnected: isConnected
    })
    this.props.toggleNetworkState(isConnected);
  };

  

  render() {
    if (!this.props.state.list.isNetwork) {
      return <MiniOfflineSign />;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offlineContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#b52424',
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 64,
    zIndex:1,
  },
  offlineText: { color: '#fff' }
});


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state
    });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {toggleNetworkState})(OfflineNotice);
```

Comment: Sure I will try that. Do you have any implementation of the above scenario in a public git??

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will try this for sure in my app. I will reply here if i get stuck somewhere.